# How to use manhattan distance in Keras

Tags: python, keras

My question is about how to use manhattan distance in Keras. 
I am working on text classification project about sentence similarity metrics. So I consider to use manhattan distance for similarity calculation. 
The loss function look like this:

```
def exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(left, right):
    ''' Helper function for the similarity estimate of the LSTMs outputs'''
    return K.exp(-K.sum(K.abs(left - right), axis=1, keepdims=True))


def manhattan_distance(left, right):
    ''' Helper function for the similarity estimate of the LSTMs outputs'''
    return K.sum(K.abs(left - right), axis=1, keepdims=True)


# The visible layer
left_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')
right_input = Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype='int32')

embedding_layer = Embedding(len(embeddings), embedding_dim, weights=[embeddings], input_length=max_seq_length, trainable=False)

# Embedded version of the inputs
encoded_left = embedding_layer(left_input)
encoded_right = embedding_layer(right_input)

# Since this is a siamese network, both sides share the same LSTM
shared_lstm = LSTM(n_hidden)

left_output = shared_lstm(encoded_left)
right_output = shared_lstm(encoded_right)

# Calculates the distance as defined by the MaLSTM model
malstm_distance = Lambda(function=lambda x: 
exponent_neg_manhattan_distance(x[0], x[1]),output_shape=lambda x: (x[0] 
[0], 1))([left_output, right_output])

# Pack it all up into a model
malstm = Model([left_input, right_input], [malstm_distance])
# Adadelta optimizer, with gradient clipping by norm
optimizer = Adadelta(clipnorm=gradient_clipping_norm)

malstm.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics= 
['accuracy'])
malstm_trained = malstm.fit([X_train['left'], X_train['right']], Y_train, 
batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=n_epoch,
                        validation_data=([X_validation['left'], 
X_validation['right']], Y_validation),
                        callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

However, this function `exponent_neg_manhattan_distance()` did not perform well actually. I searched on internet and found the original version of manhattan distance is written  like this one : `manhattan_distance`
 Then the Accuracy goes great in my model in appearance. 
Hitherto I don't which one I should use and how to explain the exp ruin the prediction for my model ?

Please help on the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I got my answer probably. exp() is normalization function. It normalises distances into [0,1], ratically, normalization can boost convergence, but it is not a must. In my case, it could be some complex reason that the precision was changed by normalization. I prolonged the training time and the result should be same. But due to the loss of float computation in data, normalization causes errors in precisions.